# can I use google cloud message for this type of home automation purposes

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, iot, chrome-gcm

hi we are working on a home automation project which can controll over mobile app 
so  can I use google cloud message for this type of home automation purposes ?
and also does the gcm requires a sim card to work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the particulars of the system you are designing. However once your Android, iOS or Chrome device is online it will be able to receive GCM (now FCM) messages. No sim card is required.